# XPath Selector Working fine with FirefoxDriver but not working with HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: testing, xpath, selenium, automation, selector

I have below code in my html page.

```
<tr id="HL1035569648A" bgcolor="#ffffff">

  <td rowspan="2" align="center" width="40"><input name="product_id" value="1035569648" onclick="syncSA(this,document.inquiry.toggleSA);hlChecked(this,document.inquiry.product_id,2,'#ffffff');" type="checkbox"></td>


  <td rowspan="2" width="90"> <div id="ysop"><a href="http://www.globalsources.com/gsol/I/Induction-cooker/p/sm/1035569648.htm"><img class="imgborder" src="http://akamai.globalsources.com.edgesuite.net/f/593/3445/5d/pdt.static.globalsources.com/IMAGES/PDT/THUMB/648/T1035569648.jpg" alt="Induction Cooker Manufacturers" title="Induction Cooker Manufacturers" onmouseout="showPPOut();" onmouseover="showPPSummary(event,'1035569648',false,rollOvInqURL);" align="left" height="80" hspace="1" vspace="1" width="80"></a> </div></td>

  <td><a href="http://www.globalsources.com/gsol/I/Induction-cooker/p/sm/1035569648.htm" name="1035569648">Induction <b>Cooker</b></a><br>
Induction Cooker with 50/60Hz Rated Frequency, 90 to 230V AC Input Voltages and 7.2kW Maximum Power<br></td>

  <td><a href="http://inductioncooktop.manufacturer.globalsources.com/si/6008838306671/Homepage.htm" title="TOPBAND Induction cookers Division">TOPBAND Induction cookers Division</a><br><a href="http://inductioncooktop.manufacturer.globalsources.com/si/6008838306671/Showroom/3000000149681/ALL.htm">47&nbsp;products</a></td>


  <td rowspan="2">China (mainland)</td>
  <td rowspan="2">
        <div class="space_filler"><a href="javascript:actionInqSingleInqPath('/gsol/GeneralManager?&amp;catalog_id=2000000003844&amp;design=clean&amp;language=en&amp;action=GetInquireNowBasket&amp;page=inquiry/InqForm&amp;template=RFI&amp;inqflow_path=NLI','InquireNow_KW',1035569648)"><img src="http://akamai.globalsources.com.edgesuite.net/f/593/3445/5d/static.globalsources.com/gsol/en/clean/images/ICON-INQUIRE.GIF" border="0" height="13" width="55"></a></div>
        <div class="space_filler"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:checkIM('/gsol/GeneralManager?&amp;catalog_id=2000000003844&amp;design=clean&amp;language=en&amp;page=im/IMSelection&amp;id=6008838306671&amp;IMSource=productsearch',340,455,'pop',null);"><img src="http://akamai.globalsources.com.edgesuite.net/f/593/3445/5d/static.globalsources.com/gsol/en/clean/images/ICON-CHAT.GIF" alt="Chat with this supplier (Login/Registration required)" title="Chat with this supplier (Login/Registration required)" border="0" height="13" width="55"></a></div>
  </td>
</tr>`
```

I want to retrieve link and description

```
<td><a href="http://www.globalsources.com/gsol/I/Induction-cooker/p/sm/1035569648.htm" name="1035569648">Induction <b>Cooker</b></a><br>
Induction Cooker with 50/60Hz Rated Frequency, 90 to 230V AC Input Voltages and 7.2kW Maximum Power<br></td>`
```

I am using below XPath:

```
//Link: http://www.globalsources.com/gsol/I/Induction-cooker/p/sm/1035569648.htm
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[starts-with(@id, 'HL')]/td[3]/a");

//Summary: Induction Cooker with 50/60Hz Rated Frequency, 90 to 230V AC Input Voltages and 7.2kW Maximum Power
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[starts-with(@id, 'HL')]/td[3]");
```

***Note: I cannot use `HL1035569648A` full `id`  because there are many Table Rows having this links and all table rows has different class name but they all starts with HL.***

This works fine with `FirefoxDriver` but it is not working with `HtmlUnitDriver`. Is anyone can help me. I am not understanding the issue.

thanks!

Comment: You are asking for help on an xpath that uses HTML that you have not shown.  We can't see the <table> or <tr> elements so will be able to provide limited help.

Secondly does the page use Javascript to render the table?  If so I'm guessing you have not turned on JavaScript emulation in HTMLUnit.

Comment: Is there still a question to answer?  The first comment says you have it working...

Answer (score 0):

Avoid XPATH locators at all costs!

You can use css just fine: tr[id^='hl'] td:eq(2) a

However hopefully you don't need that middle bit and can just do something like tr[id^='hl'] a

Comment: Why avoid XPath locators?  They are extremely powerful if used correctly.  If you had said "Avoid XPATH locators at all costs if you don't understand how they work" that would have made sense.

Comment: I didn't want to go into the details but basically XPATH locators takes longer for selenium to locate elements with than css.  For example, with older versions of IE the time difference becomes orders of magnitude more.  In addition, those that use XPATH locators tend to unintentionally create more fragile (specific) locators too.  This was an overarching theme at the recent Selenium Conference.

Comment: I would suggest that agrees with my assessment of "Avoid XPATH locators at all costs if you don't understand how they work".  I constantly see badly specced out XPaths that search the entire DOM instead of doing a targetted search in one specific area.  This does not mean That XPath s bad as a locator strategy, just that most people don't invest the time to learn how to do it properly and make a pigs ear of it.

XPath is more accurate than CSS in 90% of cases when used properly and less brittle, unfortunatly they are rarely used properly.

Comment: I also agree that if you are testing on older versions of IE it's probably worth avoiding XPath as IE didn't nativly support XPath resulting in you haveing to rely on a JavaScript implementation which due to IE's horrible JavaScript rendering engine is slow as hell, however this applies for any other locator strategy that uses IE's JavaScript rendering engine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//tr[contains(@id,"HL")]/td[3]/a
```